# LMS just like splashlearn, mathwhizz, buzzmaths

Tags: moodle, lms

I am looking for and LMS that can be customizable just like the following learning websites:
splashlearn, mathwhizz and buzzmaths.

Can Moodle be customized to give the look and feel like these learning portals  or the LMS has to be custom built from scratch?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we can change the look and feel for the Moodle LMS like the mentioned sites for that you should customize the page instead of the default page.
For customizing you can go to the login folder or else you can create a new folder for new designs. The file index.php should change according to the new design. For the new interactive design, you should be aware of HTML, CSS, Bootstrap, and basic PHP codes. Also, make sure the responsiveness of the new design.